# Create dynamic d3 color scale between two color values

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 pie chart with a color function:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(['#0075B4', '#70B5DC']);
```

If there are only two values/pieces, this works. But if there are more, I want to pick colors between the two given.

[image: d3 pie chart]

Above, with 3 pie pieces, the piece labelled "Cost 3" would have the color that is between `#0075B4` and `#70B5DC`.

Is this possible with d3? Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/9ruzntrr/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just use colors in a linear scale:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear().domain([costMin,costMax])
        .range(['#0075B4', '#70B5DC']);
```

Comment: The domain was also a crucial component I was missing.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/custom_color.html), it's `d3.scaleLinear()`